# How do I use Perl to intersperse characters between consecutive matches with a regex substitution?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

The following lines of comma-separated values contains several consecutive empty fields:

```
$rawData = 
"2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,Clear\n
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,,,\n"
```

I want to replace these empty fields with 'N/A' values, which is why I decided to do it via a regex substitution.

I tried this first of all:

```
$rawdata =~ s/,([,\n])/,N\/A/g; # RELABEL UNAVAILABLE DATA AS 'N/A'
```

which returned

```
2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,N/A,Clear\n
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,N/A,,N/A,\n
```

Not what I wanted. The problem occurs when more than two consecutive commas occur. The regex gobbles up two commas at a time, so it starts at the third comma rather than the second when it rescans the string.

I thought this could be something to do with lookahead vs. lookback assertions, so I tried the following regex out:

```
$rawdata =~ s/(?<=,)([,\n])|,([,\n])$/,N\/A$1/g; # RELABEL UNAVAILABLE DATA AS 'N/A'
```

which resulted in:

```
2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,N/A,Clear\n
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,N/A,,N/A,,N/A,,N/A\n
```

That didn't work either. It just shifted the comma-pairings by one.

I know that washing this string through the same regex twice will do it, but that seems crude. Surely, there must be a way to get a single regex substitution to do the job. Any suggestions?

The final string should look like this:

```
2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,N/A,N/A,Clear\n
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,N/A,,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A\n
```

Comment: @Zaid @ysth's answer does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't quite make out what you were trying to do in your lookbehind example, but I suspect you are suffering from a precedence error there, and that everything after the lookbehind should be enclosed in a `(?: ... )` so the `|` doesn't avoid doing the lookbehind.

Starting from scratch, what you are trying to do sounds pretty simple: place N/A after a comma if it is followed by another comma or a newline:

```
s!,(?=[,\n])!,N/A!g;
```

Example:

```
my $rawData = "2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,Clear\n2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,,,\n";

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper($rawData);
$rawData =~ s!,(?=[,\n])!,N/A!g;
print Dumper($rawData);
```

Output:

```
"2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,Clear\n2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,,,\n"
"2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,N/A,Clear\n2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A\n"
```

Comment: @ysth: Agreed. This definitely works. Is this because the lookahead assertion is non-capturing?

Comment: +1 I don't know why but I avoid assertions. In this case, I could not see the obvious because of my aversion.

Comment: @Zaid: non-capturing isn't good enough (`(?: )` wouldn't work). What matters is how much of the string has matched.  The lookahead part is not included in what s/// considers to have matched, so the next iteration of the substitution matching starts looking for a match right after the new N/A.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Note that you could open a filehandle to the data string and let `readline` deal with line endings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

my $str = <<EO_DATA;
2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,Clear
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,,,
EO_DATA

open my $str_h, '<', \$str;

while(my $row = <$str_h>) {
    chomp $row;
    print join(',',
        map { length $_ ? $_ : 'N/A'} split /,/, $row, -1
    ), "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
E:\Home> t.pl
2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,N/A,Clear
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,N/A,N/A,N/A,N/A
```

You can also use:

```
pos $str -= 1 while $str =~ s{,(,|\n)}{,N/A$1}g;
```

Explanation: When `s///` finds a `,,` and replaces it with `,N/A,` it has already moved to the character after the last comma. So, it will miss some consecutive commas if you only use

```
$str =~ s{,(,|\n)}{,N/A$1}g;
```

Therefore, I used a loop to move `pos $str` back by a character after each successful substitution.

Now, as [@ysth shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646137/how-do-i-use-perl-to-intersperse-characters-between-consecutive-matches-with-a-re/1646252#1646252):

```
$str =~ s!,(?=[,\n])!,N/A!g;
```

would make the `while` unnecessary.

Comment: Nice.  Good example that while regular expressions are frequently used in Perl, they're not always the best solution.

Comment: @Sinan: I'd rather not deal with filehandles. The data is already loaded into a string with `\n`s. Is what I want possible with one regex `s///`?

Comment: @Sinan: Evidently I have much to learn about Perl. That's a wonderful one-liner, which does exactly what I need it to do. Absolutely stunning.

Answer (score 2):

You could search for

```
(?<=,)(?=,|$)
```

and replace that with N/A.

This regex matches the (empty) space between two commas or between a comma and end of line.

Comment: +1 but it would have to be `s!(?<=,)(?=,|\n)!N/A!g;` to catch an empty field at the end of a line.

Comment: Yeah, I had just noticed that, too.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty hack version:

```
my $rawData = "2008-02-06,8:00 AM,14.0,6.0,59,1027,-9999.0,West,6.9,-,N/A,,Clear
2008-02-06,9:00 AM,16,6,40,1028,12,WNW,10.4,,,,\n";
while ($rawData =~ s/,,/,N\/A,/g) {};
print $rawData;
```

Not the fastest code, but the shortest.  It should loop through at max twice.

Comment: Concise, but like you said, quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex, but not too complicated either:

```
$string = join ",", map{$_ eq "" ? "N/A" : $_} split (/,/, $string,-1);
```

The `,-1` is needed at the end  to force `split` to include any empty fields at the end of the string.

Comment: This would fail for an empty field at the end of the line because it would contain `"\n"` which is why I `chomp` first in my `split` example.